# How to find the double covariant derivative of a general vector?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation, curvature, vector-fields

I have been reading through Carroll's GR textbook and there is a line in the derivation of the Riemann tensor that I do not understand.

$$\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu V^\rho=\partial_\mu(\nabla_\nu V^\rho) - \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\alpha} V^\rho + \Gamma^\rho_{\mu\sigma}\nabla_\nu V^\sigma.\tag{3.111}$$

We are using the Levi-Civita connection and the covariant derivative has its usual meaning. I understand how to find $\nabla_\nu V^\rho$, but my confusion is coming from how to do an additional $\nabla_\mu$.I do not know where the negative came from and why we have three terms if the covariant derivative is decomposed into two elements?

Comment: Do you understand the rule for taking the covariant derivative of an arbitrary tensor, say $\nabla_\mu T_{\alpha\beta\gamma}{}^{\delta\epsilon }$?

Answer (score 2):

The minus sign when acting over a subindex comes from requiring that
$$\nabla_\mu(V_\rho V^\rho)=(\nabla_\mu V_\rho)V^\rho+V_\rho\nabla_\mu V^\rho\stackrel{!}{=}\partial_\mu(V_\rho V^\rho),$$
since $V_\rho V^\rho$ is a scalar.

$\nabla_\nu V^\rho$ is a $(1,1)$ tensor, so its [covariant derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Coordinate_description) should carry two Christoffel symbols.

Answer (score 1):

The covariant derivative of a vector is a tensor.  You can work out the rules by acting from the out in, since the stuff inside is just a tensor.

So, you have:

$$\begin{align}
\nabla_{a}\nabla_{b}V^{c} &= \nabla_{a}\left(\nabla_{b}V^{c}\right)\\
&= \partial_{a}\left(\nabla_{b}V^{c}\right) -\Gamma_{ab}{}^{d}\nabla_{d}V^{c} + \Gamma_{ad}{}^{c}\nabla_{b}V^{d}\\
&=\partial_{a}\left(\partial_{b}V^{c} + \Gamma_{bd}{}^{c}V^{d}\right)-\Gamma_{ab}{}^{d}\nabla_{d}V^{c} + \Gamma_{ad}{}^{c}\nabla_{b}V^{d}
\end{align}$$

you get the minus sign because that's the rule for covariant derivatives acting on one-form indices, which the $b$ index is in the above.

Answer (score 0):

The covariant derivative measures how much a vector changes while moving in some direction by giving a formula for the components. The derivative term measures how the components change moving from point to point, while the Christoffel symbol measures (counteracts) the fact that the basis vectors themselves change from point to point. In fact, the Christoffel symbol $\Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\omega}$ says as you move along the $\omega$ direction, how much does your vector space change wrt the local trivialization (the $^\nu_\mu$ indices make a linear transformation). Then, if $v=v^\mu e_\mu$, the components $v^\mu$ must change to compensate for the change of $e_\mu$, this is the covariant derivative. In this case, we have something of the form $v_\nu^\mu e_\mu \omega^\nu$, now you need a derivative term for the components, a Christoffel symbol for the change of basis vectors $e_\mu$, and a Christoffel symbol for the change of basis dual vectors $\omega^\nu$ (this is induced by the one for tangent vectors by demanding functions differentiate "normally"; this gives the negative of the usual symbol).

Answer (score 0):

I find it very hard to disentangle such expressions without writing out the tensors completely.  See [this lecture by Frederic Schuller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nEaiZBbCVtI&list=PL6YPgEhGKjOGKriFcF0LCJ4J8LDY3-nyR&index=13&pp=iAQB) to see how to take (and define) the covariant derivative.

Using the method specified by Schuller, we can write out each term much more explicitly.  For example, the first term on the right-hand side is:
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\partial_\mu \left( \nabla_\nu V^{\rho} \right) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \left[ \left( \nabla_\nu V \right)^\rho \right]\\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \left[ dx^\rho \left( \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}} V \right) \right]\\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \left\{ dx^\rho \left[ \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}} \left(V^\sigma \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\sigma} \right) \right] \right\}\\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \left\{ dx^\rho \left[ \frac{\partial V^\sigma}{\partial x^\nu} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\sigma} + V^\sigma\, \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\sigma} \right) \right] \right\}\\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \left\{ dx^\rho \left[ \frac{\partial V^\sigma}{\partial x^\nu} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\sigma} + V^\sigma\, \Gamma^\beta_{\nu \sigma} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\beta} \right] \right\}\\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \left[  \frac{\partial V^\rho}{\partial x^\nu}  + V^\sigma\, \Gamma^\rho_{\nu \sigma} \right]\\
\end{split}\end{equation}
where we have used the Leibniz rule in going from line 3 to line 4, the definition of the Christoffel symbol,
$$
\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\beta} \right) = \Gamma^{\gamma}_{\alpha \beta} \,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\gamma}\,,
$$
in going from line 4 to line 5, and the action of an element of the dual basis on an element of the vector basis:
$$
dx^{\alpha} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\beta} \right) = \delta^\alpha_\beta
$$
to enable the "extraction of a component" implied by the original expression:
$$
\nabla_\nu V^\rho = \left[\nabla_\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu} \left(V\right)\right]^\rho = \left[\nabla_\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu} \left(V^\sigma \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\sigma} \right)\right]^\rho = dx^\rho \left\{ \left[\nabla_\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu} \left(V^\sigma \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\sigma} \right)\right] \right\}
$$

By carefully performing such an expansion of all other terms, one can see the equality.

Maybe for those who are familiar and happy with the manipulation of vector components without reference to their abstract counterparts will find this tedious and overwhelming.  But to me, it is the only way to really make sense of the index notation.  For example, in the last equation above, how do you know from the left-hand side of the equation whether that $\rho$ index is inside or outside of the covariant derivative? Each of the expansions in that equation give a more precise meaning to the (in my view, overly) compact notation on the left-hand side. When written in the far right-hand form, the meaning is completely transparent.